# Dtype error in function using norm pdf over a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am having issues calculating a function, while the function itself is pretty straightforward.

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math as m
from scipy.stats import norm



dff = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': ['001', '002', '003','004','005'],
                    'revenue_contribution_in_percentage': [0.2, 0.2, 0.3,0.1,0.2],
                    'BuyPrice' : [7.78,9.96,38.87,6.91,14.04],
                    'SellPrice' : [7.9725,12.25,43,7.1,19.6],
                    'margin' : [0.9725,2.2908,5.8305,0.2764,5.1948],
                    'Avg_per_week' : [71.95,75.65,105.7,85.95,66.1],
                    'StockOnHand' : [260,180,260,205,180],
                            'StockOnOrder': [0,0,0,0,0],
                            'Supplier' : ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC','ABC','ABC'],
                            'SupplierLeadTime': [12,12,12,12,12],
                            'cumul_value':[0.20,0.4,0.6,0.8,1],
                            'class_mention':['A','A','B','D','C'],
                            'std_week':[21.585,26.4775,21.14,31.802, 26.44],
                            'review_time' : [5,5,5,5,5],
                            'holding_cost': [0.35, 0.35, 0.35,0.35,0.35],
                            'aggregate_order_placement_cost': [1000, 1000,1000,1000,1000],
                            'periods' : [7,7,7,7,7]})
dff['holding_cost'] = 0.35
dff1 = dff.sort_values(['Supplier'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dff1)
df2['forecast_dts'] = 5
df2['sigma_rtlt'] = 0.5
```

i need passing some of this parameters into the function:

```
#
    a0 = -5.3925569
    a1 = 5.6211054
    a2 = -3.883683
    a3 = 1.0897299
    b0 = 1
    b1 = -0.72496485
    b2 = 0.507326622
    b3 = 0.0669136868
    b4 = -0.00329129114



    z = np.sqrt(np.log(25
                        /
                       (norm.pdf((df2['forecast_dts'])*(1-0.98)/df2['sigma_rtlt']) -
                       ((df2['forecast_dts']*(1-0.98)/df2['sigma_rtlt']))* (1-norm.cdf(df2['forecast_dts']*(1-0.98)/df2['sigma_rtlt']))) ^ 2))



    num = (a0 + a1 * z + a2 * z ^ 2 + a3 * z ^ 3)
    den = (b0 + b1 * z + b2 * z ^ 2 + b3 * z ^ 3 + b4 * z ^ 4)
    k = num / den

    return k
```

but then calculating

```
calc = calc_invUnitNormalLossApprox()*df2['sigma_rtlt']
```

returns the error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1280, in na_op
    dtype=x.dtype, typ=type(y).__name__
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

At this point I am not sure what is going on there, especially because i know the formula itself is correct, I am assuming there is something wrong with my use of norm pdf and cdf but I couldnt figure it out.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where is norm imported from?

Comment: scipy, I just updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with the `^` operator you are trying to do a `bitwise XOR` 
I think you need to use the `**` operator.

This code works

```
def calc():
    a0 = -5.3925569
    a1 = 5.6211054
    a2 = -3.883683
    a3 = 1.0897299
    b0 = 1
    b1 = -0.72496485
    b2 = 0.507326622
    b3 = 0.0669136868
    b4 = -0.00329129114



    z = np.sqrt(np.log(25
                        /
                       (norm.pdf((df2['forecast_dts'])*(1-0.98)/df2['sigma_rtlt']) -
                       ((df2['forecast_dts']*(1-0.98)/df2['sigma_rtlt']))* (1-norm.cdf(df2['forecast_dts']*(1-0.98)/df2['sigma_rtlt']))) ** 2))



    num = (a0 + a1 * z + a2 * z ** 2 + a3 * z ** 3)
    den = (b0 + b1 * z + b2 * z ** 2 + b3 * z ** 3 + b4 * z ** 4)
    k = num / den

    return k
```

Not : I have change the `^` operator to `**`